# how to view order submitted by customer to the seller?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

A customer can post an order to the seller. The problem is how can seller(ps) can view his order.Because each order may be submitted to different seller.

SLotController.php

```
public function order(Request $request)
{
$slotorder = new Slotorder;
$slotorder->name = $request->name;
$slotorder->user_name = Auth::user()->name;
$slotorder->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$slotorder->type = $request->type;
$slotorder->quantity = $request->quantity;
$slotorder->size = $request->size;
$slotorder->ps_id = ? // i dont know how to get seller id
$slotorder->save();

return view('home');
}
```

User model

```
 public function slotorder()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Slotorder::class');
}
```

SlotOrder model

```
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('User::class');
}
 public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('Ps::class');
}
```

Ps Model

```
public function slotorder()
{
return $this->hasMany('Slotorder::class');
}
```

**Update**

[image: Customer make an order to the seller]

[image: Order page]
After user click make an order, it will go to this page according to their id. For  this screenshot the id for the seller is **1**. So back to my question , how can i get the seller id when user submit the order. Therefore he can view the order in his dashboard.

Comment: `$slotorder->ps_id = ? // i dont know how to get seller id` ?? i'm not sure, but where does your `Ps` being used in your code?

Comment: Can i explain to you using screenshot ? its quite hard to explain in words

Comment: How do you determine who is the seller? Is that a random seller? Or does every user have a personal seller? What is the relationship?

Comment: @MarkWalet they can choose any seller they one.

Comment: Is the seller related to the user? Or do you have a different seller per order?

Comment: You can have different order for the seller @MarkWalet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a get route, which uses the seller id, so in the method which handles this route send the variable to the view, example:

Route

```
Route::get('giveorder/{seller_id}',Controller@method);
```

Controller Method

```
   public function method($seller_id){
     return view('giveorder',compact('seller_id'));
}
```

Create a hidden input inside your form:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{$seller_id}}" name="seller_id">
```

So now you can use this seller_id in your order method:

```
public function order(Request $request)
{
$slotorder = new Slotorder;
$slotorder->name = $request->name;
$slotorder->user_name = Auth::user()->name;
$slotorder->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$slotorder->type = $request->type;
$slotorder->quantity = $request->quantity;
$slotorder->size = $request->size;
$slotorder->ps_id = $request->seller_id;
$slotorder->save();

return view('home');
}
```